# We all know what the Pantheon is and means, don't we?

Tags: word-choice, english-comparison

I've recently found, to my surprise,  that pantheon in English also means:

> - *a group of persons most highly regarded for contributions to a field or endeavour*, i.e. :   *the pantheon of modern physics*.

This connotation is quite intuitive given the origin of the term:

> - **c. 1300, from [Pantheon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Pantheon%20&searchmode=none), name of a temple for all the gods built in Rome c. 25 B.C.** E. by Agrippa (since 609 C.E. made into the Christian church of Santa Maria Rotonda), **from Greek Pantheion (hieron) "(shrine) of all the gods,"** from pantheion, neuter of pantheios, from pan- "all" (see pan-) + theios "of or for the gods," from theos "god" (see theo-). **Sense of any group of exalted persons is first found 1590s.**

Thinking about an Italian term with the connotation of *a highly regarded group of people*, the only that comes to mind is **élite**,  a *French expression.*

Ironically *pantheon*,  a term from Ancient Rome, is  used only in English with that connotation, while  in Italian a we need a French term to convey the same concept.

Is there an Italian term with the same meaning but with a connotation and usage as effective and common as *élite*?

Comment: Sometimes people say "il gotha", though of course that's no italian word either.

Comment: (Questo è un commento pignuolo sia alla domanda che a risposte e commenti nel loro complesso.) A costo di fare l'antipatico: va bene che questo è un gruppo sull'italiano, ma cerchiamo di scrivere bene anche il francese? Le forme corrette sono *crème de la crème* e *élite*. (Ma sicuramente, per la [legge di Muphry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry's_law) avrò sbagliato qualcosa...)

Comment: @Josh61 Pantheon is a Greek word, and languages are live things, over the centuries people decided that élite was nicer. Anyway you can say the Pantheon of modern physics in Italian, but Italians will think you are talking about dead or almost dead people

Comment: @mucio -  penso che se dicessi  *un Pantheon dei fisici contemporanei* la maggior parte delle persone non capirebbe. Sebbene il Pantheon sia una luogo molto noto dubito che verrebbe subito associato al significato di èlite o ad altre espressioni simili.

Comment: Forse per i romani è un luogo, ma per gli altri é una parola che si incontra quando si studia storia e si parla delle varie regioni politeiste, il pantheon egizio, il pantheon babilonese. In quel caso pantheon é utilizzato non in senso figurato ma per indicare proprio gli dei di una religione o popolo

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there are other terms that satisfies both your conditions: effective and common. But there are similar **expressions** or **words** that are as effective but not as common:

- l'aristocrazia
- il fior fiore
- la crema (indicato da karoshi)
- l'olimpo (indicato da DaG)

The only possibile alternative that I could think of is *il meglio*, as in *il meglio del calcio* or *il meglio della fisica*. But it usually used to refer to the best results of some field, more than the best practitioners. Il *non plus ultra* has similar connotations.

Expressions such as *i campioni*, could be used; but outside of sport-related activities seems odd. I imagine somebody using something like "i campioni della logica" only with an ironical connotation.

*Maestri* as in *è uno dei maestri del settore* could be employed to indicate the best practitioners of a field, but more frequently indicates only a high degree of competence.

Comment: Also "la crema" (depending on context).

Comment: And *l'olimpo* as well, nearer to the literal meaning of “pantheon” too.

Comment: Probabilmente,  tra quelli suggeriti, i termini che seguono sono i più calzanti:                                                                                        *Aristocrazia* : 3 fig. I migliori di un gruppo, di una categoria: l'a. del calcio italiano. ( Corriere.it) 
*Crema* o *creme* : 5 fig. Insieme delle persone migliori, il fior fiore di un gruppo, di un ambiente (SIN) élite: al ricevimento era presente la c. della città. ( Corriere.it)

Comment: Personalmente non avevo mai sentito usare _la crema_ quanto piuttosto la versione francese _la créme de la créme_

Comment: Credo che l'olimpo sia la cosa piu' vicina a un 1:1. "La crema" (o elite) in particolare la percepisco come riferita soprattutto a circoli sociali di persone viventi. **"Tiger Woods fa parte della crema del golf"** vs. **"Maxwell e' nell'Olimpo dei fisici insieme a Hertz"**. "Maxwell appartiene alla crema dei fisici" non mi suona molto giusto.